# How to select a sentence in a generic HTML file with Javascript only

Tags: javascript, select, range, getselection

I need to select a complete sentence in a HTML text in which I cannot write any placeholder.

When the user selects a piece of text, I want the selection to extend from point to point. The problem I'm facing is that if I extend my sentence over the "tag limit" I'm not able to get it with the standard methods.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Attach a selection changed method:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('selectionchange', TextSelected);
   ```
2. Extend get my "range"

   ```
   function ExpandSelection()
   {
     //get the next "." (end of the sentence)
     var last = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
     while(window.getSelection().focusNode.textContent.charAt(last) != '.')
     {
       last++;
     }

     //get the previous "." (beginning of the sentence" !!! NOT WORKING
     var first = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
     while(window.getSelection().focusNode.textContent.charAt(first) != '.')
     {
       first--;
     }

     first++;

     return { start: first, end : last }
   }
   ```

My problem is, right now, that my selection is working in "moving forward" but when I try to move backward I'm not able to get the previous characters.

Does anybody has another way to do it?

Summarizing: if somebody is selecting something (also a single letter) I want the selection to expand to the complete sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by `user selects a piece of text`? You mean select with mouse? Can we see the html too?

Comment: Selects with mouse by clicking and dragging or touch long-touching. Html is very generic, it's basically text divided in <p> and <span>

Comment: @ZibaLeah Heyy, Have you found any solution regarding this point. I want to select sentences from paragraphs.